# Time Delay for code execution using WinForm App in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to delay for 2 seconds using the code below:

```
public async Task DoTasks(int seconds) {
    frmDeleteCertificateProgress f = new frmDeleteCertificateProgress();
    f.ShowDialog();
    await Task.Delay(seconds * 1000);
    f.Close();
}
```

But when the forms opens, it is not closing after the delay. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of "ShowDialog", it waits closing the form. You should use Show() method.

Comment: Awesome. Worked!

Comment: @mpora: it only works if you didn't need `ShowDialog()` in the first place. Otherwise, the user can interact outside the dialog, which is contrary to the intent of the `ShowDialog()` method.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I think, he/she hides the form. Otherwise you are right.

Comment: _"I think, he/she hides the form"_ -- what in the world makes you think that? There is nothing in the question at all that suggests that's true.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You are right. And I prefer/suggest your solution.

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: you are calling `ShowDialog()`, which has some very specific behavior. The shown form is "modal", which means it prevents any user input within the program except to that form. This is usually intentional in the use of the `ShowDialog()` method and the answer you prematurely accepted fails to preserve this behavior.

The `ShowDialog()` method doesn't return until the shown modal form (i.e. a "dialog") has been closed. So your delay and subsequent call to `Close()` the window can't happen until it's too late, i.e. the dialog window has already been closed.

There are many different ways to approach this. One of the simplest is to put the code that closes the window into a handler for the `Shown` event:

```cs
public void DoTasks(int seconds)
{
    frmDeleteCertificateProgress f = new frmDeleteCertificateProgress();
    f.Shown += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
        f.Close();
    };
    f.ShowDialog();
}
```

When the dialog window is shown, your handler will be executed. It will delay as you desire and then close the dialog window.

If you're not particular about the *exact* timing of the delay, i.e. you don't mind the delay the window is visible being shortened by the amount of time it takes to initialize the dialog, you could use a "fire and forget" async method:

```cs
public void DoTasks(int seconds)
{
    frmDeleteCertificateProgress f = new frmDeleteCertificateProgress();
    CloseAfterDelay(f, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
    f.ShowDialog();
}

private async void CloseAfterDelay(Form form, TimeSpan delay)
{
    await Task.Delay(delay);
    form.Close();
}
```